# Does a FULLTEXT index speed up LIKE conditions?

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

We have a system that is migrating from an older `VARCHAR` using `LIKE` setup to one that uses `FULLTEXT` indexes. So far everyone is enjoying the switch, but we still have some code that isn't catered to the `FULLTEXT` queries.

Currently we have a column that is a `VARCHAR(255)` and we want to remove the 255 character limit. What will happen to areas that are using the `LIKE` queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fulltext index does not help to speed up queries using `LIKE`.

But an ordinary index can speed up LIKE conditions that start with a fixed string, for example `LIKE 'FOO%'`.